# .NET "typeof" keyword missing porperties on PCL

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-10

I had a problem with one of my projects. This projcet runs fine in my WP8, WP8.1, WINRT and W10 apps. I'm trying to create the same version on android and IOS via Xamarin.

This project plays music from MS groove music (former Xbox Music).

To make a long story short, here is some code running smoothly on any Windows platform:

```
private static readonly AssemblyName assemblyName =
    new AssemblyName(typeof(SimpleServiceClient).Assembly.FullName);
```

but on Xamarin PCL the property of `Assembly.FullName` doesn't exist so I tried this:

```
private static readonly AssemblyName assemblyName =
    new AssemblyName(typeof(SimpleServiceClient).FullName);
```

Of course, my program crashes due to bad information.

Did anyone already face this problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: typeof(theType).Assembly.GetName() will return the AssemblyName.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I wrote something not clear, the property .Assembly doesn't exist. If you write "typeof(theType)" you don't see the ."Assembly" property

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was checking in a Forms project, but on the Android part, you're right, Assembly is not part of Type